# PHP include: failed to open stream: no such file in "/literally/the/exact/location/of/the/file"?

Tags: php, php-include

So while trying to include a file in php, using `include(/Users/leonaves/Sites/mysite/admin/inc/pages/dashboard.php)` (I'm running locally), PHP tells me:

> Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/leonaves/Sites/mysite/admin/inc/page_request.php on line 86.

I have tried including from a relative path, from an absolute path, declaring the root in a variable etc. etc. I have no idea how to make this file include the other. PHP refuses to find it AT THE EXACT LOCATION IT IS. Any help would be amazing, thank you.

Comment: Is this location accessible by the webserver? Could it be a permissions issue.

Comment: Could you `var_dump(file_exists($filename));` and `var_dump(is_readable($filename));` ?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the drive letter in the path? (It looks like you're using Windows.)

Comment: Copy that path and run on the command line `ls -l <paste-path-here>`

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 No, that looks like MacOS.  `/Users/username/Sites` is the default OSX personal site location.

Comment: @Touki: true on both counts, but include($filename) gives the same error.

Comment: @deceze -rwxr-xr-x  1    7.2K 30 Jul 16:31 /Users/leonaves/Sites/mysite/admin/inc/pages/dashboard.php

Comment: @Orangepill definitely accessible, 744.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Correct.

Answer (score 0):

PHP executes only scripts found in directories specified in [`open_basedir`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir). Your path is probably not allowed.

Comment: It's the exact same message with php-fpm, on Linux at least.

Comment: open_basedir isn't defined in my php.ini, what's the default behaviour?

Comment: Default is to allow everything.